# How to give a consistent mathematical explanation to a paradoxical divergent/convergent phenomena.

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

How can be explained, in a "clean" mathematical way, the "stabilization" of the different digits in the following divergent sequence?

$$\tan(89°)=57.28996163...$$

$$\tan(89.9°)=572.9572134...$$

$$\tan(89.99°)=5729.577893...$$

$$\tan(89.999°)=57295.77951...$$

$$\tan(89.9999°)=572957.7951...$$

etc...

Comment: I don't know but I guess it has something to do with the fact that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cot10^{-n-1}}{\cot10^{-n}}=10\ ?$$

Comment: What is *paradoxical*?

Comment: @mrf I mean that there is an apparent paradox in having a convergence of the digits whereas the sequence is divergent...

Comment: @bof You are right, due to the series for $\cot(x)=1/x+...$, but why these digits $5,7,2,9,5,7...$

Comment: Did you check the suggested duplicate? $180/\pi = 57.2957795131\ldots$.

Comment: @mrf thanks, I checked it and acknowledged it as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \to 1$ when $x \to 0$, so $\cos(90^\circ-x)=\sin{x} \approx x$, meaning when you're $10$ times closer to $90^\circ$ cosine is $10$ times smaller and the tangent is $10$ times bigger because sine is approximately equal to one.